# Teradata Regular Expressions - Repetition not supported in zero-length assertions?

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I need to use a look behind with repetition, but it doesn't look like it's supported. Is there an alternative syntax?

The intention is to match 'Third', when it follows 'First' and arbitrary number of 'R's and 'Second'.

Without the repetition character this compiles, but obviously fails to match.

```
SELECT 'FirstRRRRRSecondThird' AS inputString,
       REGEXP_INSTR(inputString,'(?<=FirstRSecond)Third',1);
```

But when I try to add repetition, I get 'The pattern specified is not a valid pattern.'

```
SELECT 'FirstRRRRRSecondThird' AS inputString,
       REGEXP_INSTR(inputString,'(?<=FirstR+Second)Third',1);
```

also, {1,M} fails

```
SELECT 'FirstRRRRRSecondThird' AS inputString,
       REGEXP_INSTR(inputString,'(?<=FirstR{1,}Second)Third',1);
```

This is a pretty vanilla regular expressions so it seems far-fetched that it wouldn't be supported.

Comment: Most _vanilla_ regex engines that support lookbehinds, don't support variable width sub-expressions within them. For speed, they want to decrease the current position pointer an exact amount and do a `strncmp()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a better description. The intention is to match 'Third', when it follows 'First' and arbitrary number of 'R's and 'Second'. But from sln's comment it looks like I might be hosed.

Comment: Options: Convert it to `(?:FirstR+Second)Third` or `FirstR+Second(Third)`

Comment: Could you use: `'First[R]+(Second)+Third'` Not entirely sure what you are trying to match exactly though.

Comment: @JNevill  The intention is to match 'Third', when it follows 'First' and arbitrary number of 'R's and 'Second'. This is a concocted example, what I'm really trying to do is get all the tables a procedure inserts into, so I want to pick up the table name which follows 'INSERT' some amount of whitespace ' INTO ' tableName

Comment: @sln That did the trick!

Comment: Assuming that you extract that info from DBQL data: Why don't you simply switch on the OBJECTS option (if you're not interested in column details use NO COLUMNS)? There's an undocumented variant of the REGEXP_SUBSTR UDF with a 6th parameter indicating the subpattern to extract: `RegExp_Substr_gpl(inputString,'(FirstR+Second)(Third)',1,1,'i',2)` returns the 2nd match.

Answer (score 0):

Look at: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
(describing *lookahead* and *lookbehind*) and find title:
*Important Notes About Lookbehind*

The second paragraph starts with:

*Many regex flavors, including those used by Perl, (...)
only allow **fixed-length** strings*

So you can not use quantifiers within any lookbehind.

I think, the way to circumvent this limitation is:

- use "ordinary" match (instead of the lookbehind),
- after that put your original pattern, maybe in a capturing group.

Example:

```
FirstR+SecondThird
```

1. `FirstR+Second` matches `First`, any number of `R` characters
   and `Second`.
2. Then `Third` matches `Third`.

This regex also matches what you intend: `Third` after what you described
in your post.

By the way: I suppose that you posted a simplified regex and in real life
instead of `First`, `Second` and `Third` there will be more complicated
expressions.

**Additional remark**

You can delete the third argument of `REGEXP_INSTR` (1), because its default
value is just **1** (look for match, starting from the **first** char of
the source string).